# Faint line under legend using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have the current CSS:

```
fieldset.bordered {
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1em 1em 1em !important;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0 !important;
}
legend.bordered {
   border-style: none;
   border-width: 0;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   border-bottom:none;
}
```

With a JSP that has:

```
      <fieldset class="bordered">
      <legend>Current Property Manager</legend>
          <form:input type="text" path="currentPropertyManager" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Property Manager Name"/><strong><form:errors path="currentPropertyManager" type="text" htmlEscape="false" class="text-danger"/></strong><br>
          <form:input type="tel" path="currentPropertyManagerPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Property Manager Phone" /><strong><form:errors path="currentPropertyManagerPhone" type="text" htmlEscape="false" class="text-danger"/></strong><br>
      </fieldset>
```

but it produces a faint line under the legend.

[image]

How do I get rid of the faint line?  I tried border=0px and searching on SO.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling is correct. The problem is that your `legend.bordered` style is not applying to the `legend` element because the css selector does not match it.

To make it match, you either need to change it to `.bordered legend` (or even `fieldset.bordered legend`), or add the `bordered` class to the `legend` element (personally I prefer the first approach). Once you have done this, it will no longer have the feint line as your `border-bottom` style will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The line is the `border-bottom` property applied to legend. The border bottom is initially set to `1px solid #e5e5e5` color. You can set the `border-bottom` property of legend to `0px`. I tried it as an inline style and it works!